# Return name of the employee who having top salary with join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

here is the situation. I have two tables, one is table `Tbl_employ`, second is `tbl_details`.

```
Tbl_employ
----------
id  | name 
1   | Ravi
2   | ram 
3   | sham
4   | john

Tbl_details
-----------
id   | salary   | emp_id
1    | 500      | 1
2    | 200      | 2 
3    | 400      | 3
4    | 501      | 4
```

I want to return the `name of the employee` who has top salary in `tbl_detail`.

What will be the join query for this condition?

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestion? ok. User `top 1`, and `order by salary`. Question: is this a homework?

Comment: i need it . no matter it is homework or office work .. @aleksey.berezan ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT TOP(1) name
FROM Tbl_employ e INNER JOIN Tbl_details d ON e.id = d.emp_id
ORDER BY d.salary DESC;
```

Essentially, this joins the two tables on the key fields (`id` and `emp_id`), returning only a single result (`TOP(1)`) that is the maximum `salary` row (`ORDER BY d.salary DESC`).

Comment: hey.. thanks buddy .. thanks a lot . this is accurate. thanks for instant reply sir ..

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the answer of @Max Vernon.
You can also do it by another way. Please try this

```
select t.name from (
select Distinct top 1 salary ,name
from Tbl_employ as E
left outer join Tbl_details as D on D.empid=E.id
order by salary desc
 ) as t
```

you can check it here [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cd6b/18)